# Breeze Expand Property

Tags: breeze

I'm getting the following exception when I try to use Expand on any navigation property.

```
    $id: "1",
    $type: "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
    Message: "An error has occurred.",
    ExceptionMessage: "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Include'",
    ExceptionType: "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException",
    StackTrace: " at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__b.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous  location where exception was thrown --- at  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
```

If I put the include inside the Breeze controller everything works fine. If I do not and just use expand on the client, I get that error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is the URL used to try to retrieve the data

```
   /breeze/maxsys/CallOutcomes?$expand=CallOutcomeAction
```

Here is the model

```
[Table("CallOutcomes")]
public class CallOutcome {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsInternal { get; set; }


    public int CallOutcomeActionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CallOutcomeActionId")]
    [InverseProperty("CallOutcomes")]
    public CallOutcomeAction CallOutcomeAction { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CallOutcomeHistory> CallOutcomeHistories { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller looks as follows ( I removed some of the other get methods )

```
[BreezeController]
[Authorize]
[RequireHttps]
public class MaxsysController : ApiController

    protected IMaxsysBreezeRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public MaxsysController(IMaxsysBreezeRepository repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<CallOutcome> CallOutcomes()
    {
        return Repository.CallOutcomes;
    } 
}
```

The error is coming from this method in the BreezeQueryableAttribute.cs

```
    public virtual IQueryable ApplyExpand(IQueryable queryable, string expandsQueryString, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        (from s in expandsQueryString.Split(new char[] { ',' }) select s.Trim()).ToList<string>().ForEach(delegate (string expand) {
            queryable = (IQueryable) ((dynamic) queryable).Include(expand.Replace('/', '.'));
        });
        return queryable;
    }
```

The parameter values are

```
   queryable = {SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
N'b1d28373-98a2-4a88-9733-7872acd28bd2' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[IsInternal] AS [IsInternal], 
[Extent1].[CallOutcomeActionId] AS [CallOutcomeActionId], 
N'CallOutcomeAction' AS [C2], 
N'b1d28373-98a2-4a88-9733-7872acd28bd2' AS [C3], 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Extent2].[Description] AS [Description1]
FROM  [dbo].[CallOutcomes] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CallOutcomeActions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CallOutcomeActionId] = [Extent2].[Id]}

expandsQueryString = "CallOutcomeAction"

    HttpRequestMessage ={Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://127.0.0.1:82/breeze/maxsys/CallOutcomes?$expand=CallOutcomeAction', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Accept: text/html
  Accept: application/xhtml+xml
  Accept: application/xml; q=0.9
  Accept: */*; q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding: gzip
  Accept-Encoding: deflate
  Accept-Encoding: sdch
  Accept-Language: en-US
  Accept-Language: en; q=0.8
  Host: 127.0.0.1:81
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
  User-Agent: (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
  User-Agent: AppleWebKit/537.36
  User-Agent: (KHTML, like Gecko)
  User-Agent: Chrome/27.0.1453.94
  User-Agent: Safari/537.36
}}
```

Comment: What does your controller method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Preliminaries

Are you sure that you can query the `MaxsysController.CallOutcomes` endpoint *without expand*?

Are you sure that `Repository.CallOutcomes` is returning the proper EF concrete type?

You tried something like the following inside the controller's `CallOutcomes()`:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IQueryable CallOutcomes()
    {
        var foo = Repository.CallOutcomes  // break here; remove later.
                  .Include('CallOutcomeAction').ToList();
        return Repository.CallOutcomes;
    }
```

At the break you've confirmed that the method succeeded w/o failure and that `foo` has values.

### Next

Once you've confirmed those points, I think my next move would be to remove the `[RequireHTTPS]`. I haven't tried that lately and it's not easy for me to set that up quickly on my end. There is a possibility that we screwed up and there is interference between the `[RequireHTTPS]` attribute and the `[BreezeController]` attribute.

Also try putting `[RequireHTTPS]` before `[BreezeController]`. It shouldn't matter; I'm just guessing now. I'll await your report and then we can move on from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 1. Yes, the endpoint does work without the expand. 2. Repository.CallOutcomes does return the correct concrete type. 3. I added include in the controller and that did work, but I want to call expand from the client. 4. I removed RequireHTTPS attribute and still get the same problem. I also removed the repository and created a EFContextProvider<MaxsysDbContext> object within the controller.

Comment: ... you left me hanging. Did that work? Either way we have mystery to solve. But if it didn't, I'm suspecting some interference with the action handlers in the Web API.

Comment: The error is occurring in BreezeQueryableAttribute.cs in the ApplyExpand method. I put the parm values for this method above. It crashes right at the Foreach where the include is referenced.

Comment: If I run the Breeze.Learn sample from GITHUB and upgrade to the latest version of breeze and access http://localhost:3818/breeze/Northwind/Orders?$expand=OrderDetails, I get a similar error if I add the [BreezeController] attribute to the NorthwindController.

Comment: Note to anyone reading this thread: @nmushov discovered the cause which was pre-release Web API. See his answer above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved. There was some pre-release software that was installed to test the CORS support in Web API. Once I removed those changes, expand ended up working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmm. I'm glad you found it. But I'm not happy that there is something on the horizon that threatens the Breeze.net behavior. Would you please supplement your answer by identifying which pre-release software you tried. I can then at least consider preparing for future coexistence with that software.

Comment: Sure, I had the Microsoft ASP.NET Cross-Origin Support installed (Microsoft.AspNet.Cors 5.0.0-rtm130525),  Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Cross-Origin (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors (5.0.0-rtm130525), and Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Web Host, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (5.0.0-rtm-13025)

Answer (score 1):

I've also experienced this issue and tracked it down to the application of a BreezeQueryable annotation.

Exception:

ExceptionMessage: "'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery' does not contain a definition for 'Include'",

Endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[BreezeQueryable(PageSize = 1000)] //1000 row limit
public IQueryable<Postcode> Postcodes()
{
    return _db.Context.Postcodes;
}
```

Calling script:

```
var qry = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from('Postcodes')
                .where('Name', breeze.FilterQueryOp.StartsWith, searchTerm)
                .orderBy('PostcodeId')
                .expand('State')
                .take(25);
```

To fix, simply remove the [BreezeQueryable] annotation:

```
[HttpGet]
//[BreezeQueryable(PageSize = 1000)] //1000 row limit
public IQueryable<Postcode> Postcodes()
{
    return _db.Context.Postcodes;
}
```

Edit - obviously this is not 'fixed'. 
Looks like an issue in the Breeze WebApi assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this problem when I tried to limit the page size returned by my actions using the BreezeQueryableAttribute on the action. Without the attribute, the action returns the expected data. Like gopheruk, I believe there is currently a bug in Breeze.

**Library versions:**

I'm **not** using any pre-release libraries, and everything is up to date in nuget.

- Breeze 1.4.2 (Breeze.WebApi 1.4.0.0, Breeze.WebApi.EF 1.4.0.0)
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.30506
- EntityFramework 5.0.0

**The request:**

```
http://localhost/breeze/Data/MyObjects?$filter=Id%20eq%201&$expand=User
```

**On the server:**

```
[BreezeController]
public class DataController : ApiController
{

    //...

    [HttpGet]
    [BreezeQueryable(PageSize = 30)] //if this line is commented out, everything works
    public IQueryable<MyObject> MyObjects()
    {
        return _myObjectRepository.All(User.Identity);
    }

}
```

**The response:**

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<MyObject>' does not contain a definition for 'Include'","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException","StackTrace":"   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )\r\n   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass14.<ApplyExpand>b__11(String expand)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.ApplyExpand(IQueryable queryable, String expandsQueryString)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.ApplySelectAndExpand(IQueryable queryable, NameValueCollection map)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.BreezeQueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"}
```